Storing latitude and longitude as point in PostgreSQL database and handling in Java
I'm working on a project where I need to store latitude and longitude in coordinates field in a PostgreSQL database. I've decided to use the Point data type in PostgreSQL to represent these coordinates efficiently. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to handle this in Java and how to declare in entity class.
For example:
double lat =17.4343,
double lon =76.4343

Better approach to store the coordinates to store in db and how to take in entity class.
Give me best suggestions to store the coordinates to PostgreSQL db

You can just store 2 double values and you're done, what's the drawback of that?

@f1sh Because then you have to ignore all the built-in support postgres has for points, such as interesting ways to index them, and a whole boatload of operations for all the geometric types psql supports such as circles and such. You have a JPA mindset (dbs? Just implementation details for storing data. SQL is scary, db features are best not used at all, then you have DB independence!) perhaps. In such a mindset, indeed, there's no point (heh) to using point. But I don't think OP is in that mindset. Opinion: It's a silly mindset.

Use PostGIS. The PostgreSQL's built-in geometry types are fairly primitive and limited in what you can do with them. Although PostGIS is an extension, it's the de-facto standard for GIS-related operations in Postgres. JTS is a Java rewrite of C++ GEOS that's powering PostGIS.

Read the documentation: The Postgres JDBC driver docs: Geometric data types.
The key is to use the PGpoint class (there are more 'geometric' types, and a java class is available for each of them), from the postgres JDBC driver.
You can easily retrieve points from queries, as well as set them in queries:
PreparedStatement ps = ...;
PGpoint p = new PGpoint(1.5, 2.5);
ps.setObject(colRef, p);

ResultSet rs = .....;
PGpoint q = rs.getObject(colRef, PGpoint.class);
System.out.printf("Coord: [%f, %f]\n", q.x, q.y);

NB: The docs suggest you have to cast. You don't - The 2-args method of getObject is is nicer on the eyes and a bit more standard. But, if you really wanna cast - it's an option, of course.

entity class::
import org.postgresql.geometric.PGpoint;
@Column(name = "coordinates")
private PGpoint coordinates;
In service::
 PGpoint pGpoint = new PGpoint(lat, lon);
accountTransactionMeta.setCoordinates(pGpoint);
accountTransactionMetaRepository.save(accountTransactionMeta);
but getting below error::
could not execute statement [ERROR: column "coordinates" is of type point but expression is of type bytea\n  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n  Position: 179]

It is not c lear what 'accountTransactionMeta' is, what library you are using to do this, and so on. This is a different question from what you asked.

Use PostGIS geometry(Point) type instead. The db extension comes bundled with JDBC extension objects.
The built-in geometry types are fairly primitive and limited in what you can do with them. Although PostGIS is an extension, it's the de-facto standard for GIS-related operations in Postgres. Compare the list of built-in functions and operators with the PostGIS list to get an idea.
There's a small example in the doc, and here's larger end-to-end example of a working app.
